# Reimporting an EML file through IMAP

Tags: imap, eml

I have a bunch of .eml files exported/archived using 'archivemail'. Now I need to restore
some the files completely on the IMAP server. Is there some simple tool taking an .eml/mail file with multiple emails and restoring it on an IMAP server

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mail.dll [.NET IMAP library](http://www.limilabs.com/mail) for that:

```
using (Imap imap = new Imap())
{
    imap.Connect("server"); // or ConnectSSL
    imap.Login("user", "password");

    string eml = File.ReadAllText("email.eml");    
    imap.UploadMessage("INBOX", eml);

    imap.Close();
}
```

Mail.dll can also parse the .eml files if you need to implement some custom logic before uploading:

```
IMail email = new MailBuilder().CreateFromEml(eml);
```

Please note however that this is a commercial product I helped to develop.